Dynamically naming a variable in R
I am working in R.
I have two variables defined:
year_current <- 24
year_last <- 23

Currently I have a variable and it is defined like  this:
SQL_flatfile_23_24 <-  "[schema_24].[liverun_23_24]"

However I want it to update dynamically. I.e. when I update year_current and year_last, I don't then need to update that line of code too.
I think it will have to have something to do with sym, or !! or :-, but I can't get it to work!
sym(paste0("SQL_flatfile_", year_last, "_", year_current)) = 
        paste0("[schema_", year_current, "][liverun_", year_last, "_", year_current, "]")


The left hand side of this seems to run ok - i.e. it is not outputting as a string?
> sym(paste0("SQL_flatfile_", year_last, "_", year_current))
SQL_flatfile_2023_2024  


But running the whole thing does not work...
Does anyone have any ideas?

That’s normally what you’d use (named) lists or vectors or data.frames for. Can you explain your use-case? Are you sure that your approach is a suitable solution (the answer is virtually always “no”!)?

I run my code yearly.
A lot of the code is defining schemas and table names to then write to a SQL database. Next year, year_current would be 25 and year_last would be 24. I don't want to go through every line of code and update 24 to 25 etc.
Is this still bad practise to have it dynamically do you think?

I think you misunderstood what I am suggesting. You should definitely not change your code if the data changes. Just run the same code. In fact, from your comment it sounds like your variable names shouldn’t be dynamic at all.

So for example:
SQL_flatfile_23_24 <-  "[schema_24].[liverun_23_24]"  would be better as:
SQL_flatfile_last_current <-  paste0("[schema_", year_current, "].[liverun_", year_last, "_", year_current, "]")
So variable name is now static and the value it takes is the only dynamic bit?

Unless you need to refer to multiple years at once: yes. There’s nothing gained from including the years in the variable name. And if you need to refer to multiple data sets at once, that’s what lists or data.frames are for.

You may use assign :
year_current <- 24
year_last <- 23

assign(paste("SQL_flatfile", year_last, year_current, sep = "_"), 
       paste0("[schema_", year_current, "].[liverun_", year_last, "_", year_current, "]"))


You “may”, but you should almost certainly not. This is a bad solution for 99.99999999…% of cases.

@KonradRudolph why is this a bad solution - it does seem to work? Genuinely interested in best practise for my code so interested to hear your thoughts.

@fe108 Because it makes your code vastly more complex, harder to understand and harder to debug than if you used more appropriate solutions.

@fe108 In fact, variable names are part of the code, not the data. You should consider code as static: if your code needs to change when the data changes, that’s a red flag: you’ve made a mistake. (There are exceptions but like I said these are insanely rare; and nothing indicates that your case is an exception.)

@KonradRudolph thanks for your thoughts. I will have another think about the code
